# Substitute duplicates with different variables

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to do the following. In my panel dataset I observe an individual at different ages. The data is imprecise though, so I might have the same age repeated for an individual over different years (e.g. [id=1, year=2000, age=40] and [id=1, year=2001, age=40]. I want to identify these observation and substitute them with a different variable, that corresponds to 'year' - 'year of birth'.

So I'd have something like:

| id | year | age | year_birth | age_dv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 40 | 1960 | 40 |
| 1 | 2001 | 40 | 1960 | 41 |
| 1 | 2002 | 42 | 1960 | 42 |

Which I want to replace with:

| id | year | age | year_birth | age_dv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 40 | 1960 | 40 |
| 1 | 2001 | 41 | 1960 | 41 |
| 1 | 2002 | 42 | 1960 | 42 |

I have done this in Stata before and there I would created a column that identifies duplicates according to id and age (for instance 1 if it's a duplicate) and replace those variables using the condition on this new "tag" column.

Final result looks like:

| id | year | age | year_birth | age_dv | duplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 40 | 1960 | 40 | 0 |
| 1 | 2001 | 41 | 1960 | 41 | 1 |
| 1 | 2002 | 42 | 1960 | 42 | 0 |

Can I do the same in R? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c('duplicate', 'age') := .(+(duplicated(age)), 
        year - year_birth), .(id)]
df
#   id year age year_birth age_dv duplicate
#1:  1 2000  40       1960     40         0
#2:  1 2001  41       1960     41         1
#3:  1 2002  42       1960     42         0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L), year = 2000:2002, age = c(40L, 
40L, 42L), year_birth = c(1960L, 1960L, 1960L), age_dv = 40:42), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks! If i try it on my data though it reports the following error 

"Error in `:=`(c("duplicate", "age2"), .(+(duplicated(age)), year - year_birth)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")."

Comment: @Maria that error is because your dataset is not data.frame.  I converted the data.frame to data.table with `setDT`

Comment: Ok makes sense. Should i set it back to be a data frame afterwards?

Comment: @Maria Yes, you can change it back to data.frame with `setDF`, but it is more efficient to use `data.table`

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you could use

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(duplicate=duplicated(age)+0,
         age = year-year_birth)
```

Tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="
id  year    age year_birth  age_dv
1   2000    40  1960    40
1   2001    40  1960    41
1   2002    42  1960    42", header=TRUE)
```